# Show that the intersection of two subgroups is the identity or that they're both equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and suppose $A,B<G$ with order $7$, i.e. $|A|=|B|=7.$ Show that either $A\cap B=\{1\}$ or $A=B.$

My attempt:
Observe that $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $B.$ Then, by Lagrange's Theorem, the intersection must divide $7$. So its either $1$ or $7$. Therefore, either $A\cap B=\{1\}$ or $A=B.$ $\square$

For the last part, would I need to give more of an explanation?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes I think you need to justify why $A=B$. You said if $|A \cap B| = 1$ then $A \cap B ={1}$, what happens if $|A \cap B|= 7$?

Comment: By "the intersection must divide $7$" did you mean "the order of the intersection must divide $7$?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is ok, but I think you should justify the steps $|A\cap B|=1\implies A\cap B=\{1\}$ and $|A\cap B|=7\implies A=B$ a bit more. It is easy but still better to make explicit.